# Math Formula Into Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have this Maths formula which i tried to convert into Oracle function.
This is how it must work, **taxableIncome** loops through the table,it picks the first line on the table and if it is more  than **CumulativeAmount**,it subtracts **CumulativeAmount** from **taxableIncome** and keeps the **remainder**,it multiplies the **CumulativeAmount** and **Percentage** to get a value(x),takes the remainder and go next line in the table and subtract the **CumulativeAmount** from the remainder.when the remainder is less than the **CumulativeAmount**,it will apply the 17.5 on the remainder.Later I will sum the (x) values to get a total value. The values are not calculating properly.

[image: This is the table I used to write the function]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function CalculateIncomeTax(periodId NVARCHAR2, 
employeeId NVARCHAR2,paygroupcode PAYROLL_MASTER.PAY_PAY_GROUP_CODE%type,
taxableIncome NUMBER)
return NUMBER 
AS
IncomeTax NUMBER (10,2); 
BEGIN
SELECT 
 coalesce(SUM(                       
  CASE WHEN (taxableIncome > T.TAX_CUMMULATIVE_AMOUNT) THEN (taxableIncome - 
  T.TAX_CUMMULATIVE_AMOUNT)* (T.TAX_PERCENTAGE/ 100)                            
  ELSE 0.00 END
    ) ,0)                       
  INTO IncomeTax    
  FROM TAX_LAW T  JOIN PAY_GROUP P ON P.PAY_FORMULA_ID   =T.TAX_FORMULA_ID                         
  WHERE P.PAY_CODE  = paygroupcode;
return IncomeTax;  
end;
 /
```

For example:

```
taxableIncome= 1000,the function must loop on the first line on the 
table CummulativeAmount=261,so 1000-261=739, and 0*739=0,0 is 
value(x), 
next loop 739>70,739 is the remainder,so 739-70=669, and (5/100)*70 
=3.5,3.5 is value(x),   
next loop 669>100,669-100=569, (10/100)*100=10,10 is value(x),
now 569 < 2810, so (17.5/100)*569=99.575,99.575 is value(x).
so we sum all x  =0+3.5+10+99.575= 113.075
```

if taxableIncome = 300,300 is greater than 261 in the table so we will use the percentage of 0 on it,but we will get 0.now (300-261) is less than 70 so the percentage of 5 cannot be used on it so the Incometax is 0.But 17.5 will be applied on (300-261) to get 6.825,Total IncomeTax is  6.825.This is the logic behind the calculations.I want to used while statement on calculation it.

Comment: "The values are not calculating properly" - explain. What values did you expect, based on what input, what return value are you getting, and why is this wrong? Please edit your question and provide sample input **AS TEXT, NOT AS AN IMAGE**, and a complete walk-through of what the calculations are supposed to be. Thanks.

Comment: which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @BobJarvis,you didn't even read the question well,I explained how the math formula must work.If I knew why it my function was wrong,I won't come here and ask.You are not helping the situation.

Comment: @APC,I'm using Oracle  version 12c

Comment: There are things that are still unclear about this question.  What if `taxableIncome = 300`, say?  What if `taxableIncome = 10000`?  What is the purpose of the `PAY_GROUP` table mentioned in your function?  Also, please note your worked example calculation has two errors: `669-100` is `569`, not `559`, and `0+33.45+55.9+97.825` is `187.175`, not `232.725`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward,i edited the example.i got it wrong at first.I have explained the logic well.from the logic if IncomeTax is less than or equal to 261,Income Tax is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function CalculateIncomeTax2(taxableIncome NUMBER)
return NUMBER 
AS
IncomeTax NUMBER (10,2) := 0;
TaxableRemainder NUMBER := taxableIncome;
BEGIN
for r in (select tax_id, tax_percentage, tax_cummulative_amount
          from incometax
          order by tax_id)
loop
    if TaxableRemainder > r.tax_cummulative_amount then
        TaxableRemainder := TaxableRemainder - r.tax_cummulative_amount;
        incometax := incometax + (r.tax_cummulative_amount * r.tax_percentage / 100);
    else
        incometax := incometax + (TaxableRemainder * r.tax_percentage / 100);
        exit; 
    end if;
end loop;

return IncomeTax;
end; 
/
```